# Exception in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm doing a Music project. You know we must have a seek bar to seek to posistion of MediaElement if you need. But when the slider (seek bar) is running, the IDE throw a exception say that: Exception:Thrown: Slider TargetType does not match type of element Control.
I dont think this problem appear due by code, I think it appear when i design slider for seekbar. Pls help me! Sorry for my english. This is code:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomStyleForSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Placement="Top" Height="4" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Placement="Bottom" Height="4" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        <Border x:Name="TrackBackground"  BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="4.0" Grid.Row="1" >
                            <Canvas Margin="-6,-1">
                                <Rectangle Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Height="4.0" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1.0"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Border>
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}"/>
                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}"/>
                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Background="Black"/>
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Should be more clear, without code it's hard to tell you where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the TargetType property on any Styles or ControlTemplates you have created and make sure that it is appropriate for the type of control you are applying the Style/ControlTemplate to.